# KineticJS: Removing a shape from a layer vs. setting visible to false?

Tags: kineticjs

How much overhead is there to keeping an invisible shape in a layer vs. adding and removing shapes?

I'm building a lightweight presentation manager where shapes are continually added and removed as slides are flipped through.  I'll often reuse shapes from previous slides, so many shapes won't be one-time use (plus it is also possible to scroll backwards through the slides, reusing the original shapes).

In practice, I can't tell the difference, but I thought I'd check for opinions.  Right now I'm defaulting to full add and remove with each slide, but worry that will create a lag if I have many shapes going from one slide to the next.  If there isn't such an overhead, why was the visible flag added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node.remove` and `node.hide` both keep a reference to the node so the overhead is almost identical.

`node.destroy` will destroy the node and the garbage collector will eventually reclaim its resources.

Comment: Is the only distinction between 'node.remove' and 'node.hide' the fact that hide keeps track of the association with a specific layer and remove doesn't?

Comment: Yes, that's the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing anything performance critical allocations and garbage collection are a couple of the worst possible things for performance in that they'll noticeably drop your framerate.

Ideally you'd create everything when the interactive component is loading, and then do not delete or create any objects during interactivity or animations. I'm not sure about KinectJS, but The overhead of an invisible object usually isn't much at all.

Comment: KineticJS objects are rather weighty in terms of resources so hidden objects still take up a relatively large amount of resources.

Comment: I'll keep tabs on memory usage.  For now, I wasn't planning on destroying any of the shapes, just debating between removing them and hiding them.  I am, indeed, creating the entire presentation first, and then playing it after images are all loaded, etc.

Comment: Usually you're trading increased memory usage for decreased perceived lags. Most game engines / frameworks have a scheduled update method for some or all objects. Just make sure that's not scheduled while the objects are hidden.